Oracle 19c Substract workdays?
I was searching in the web for an easy solution to substracting a number of workdays in Oracle SQL like in Excel or Google Sheets, but it seems the only way is to either create functions or elaborate arithmetic CASE-based calculations to achieve such result.
Still, I see most of these answers are from 2018, 2019, &c. Is there any updated method or has this feature been included in the basic Oracle package?
Thanks,

There is no built-in package. You do not need to use a CASE expression or functions. The linked duplicate uses a calculation to find the number of full weeks over the range and then the number of part weeks at the start and end of the range.

Hi @MT0, do you happen to have a formula that can get the resulting date from the subtraction of a number of workdays from a date? I saw in your link it only reads how to retrieve the number of workdays from two dates.

Which days do you consider work days? As far as I know, most countries have at least Monday to Thursday. Some have the Friday off, some have the Saturday off, some have the Sunday off, and some have a two-days weekend. Then, holidays are not working days, or are they? Your solution will heavily depend on your definition of a work day.

If you question is:

How do I add/subtract a number of working/business days to a starting date dt?

Assuming you define working/business days as Monday-Friday and Saturday and Sunday as non-working days. (If you want to have a different set of work days then you can use similar logic, you will just have to offset the date by the number of days difference for the start of the week before performing the calculation and then reverse the process afterwards or for a different length (contiguous) working week replace 5 with the length of the week.)
You can:

Find the start of the week using TRUNC(dt, 'IW') (always midnight on Monday)
Find how many days from the start of the week the date is using dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW')
Find out how many business/working days into the week the date is using LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) (i.e. take the previous result and if it is Saturday or Sunday then that is only a full 5 working days, and the current date can be assumed to be equivalent to Monday at the start of the next week because you've gone past Friday of the current week).
Add the number of days you want to offset the date by to that value to give the total number of working days offset from the start of the week.
For every 5 working days, add a full week to the starting date. For every part working week, add that many days.

Like this:
SELECT dt,
       days,
       -- Start of Week
       TRUNC(dt, 'IW')
       -- Add Full Business Weeks (multiples of 5 days)
       + FLOOR((LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) + days)/5)
         * INTERVAL '7' DAY
       -- Add Part Business Weeks  
       + LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) + days
       - FLOOR((LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) + days)/5) * 5
         AS offset_day
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt, days) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 0, -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2.5, -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2, -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 5.5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 5.5, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 0.2, 5 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DT
DAYS
OFFSET_DAY




2024-09-23 00:00:00 (MON)
-3
2024-09-18 00:00:00 (WED)


2024-09-25 12:00:00 (WED)
-3
2024-09-20 12:00:00 (FRI)


2024-09-25 00:00:00 (WED)
-1
2024-09-24 00:00:00 (TUE)


2024-09-26 00:00:00 (THU)
2
2024-09-30 00:00:00 (MON)


2024-09-25 00:00:00 (WED)
7
2024-10-04 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-09-28 12:00:00 (SAT)
0
2024-09-30 00:00:00 (MON)


2024-09-28 12:00:00 (SAT)
7
2024-10-09 00:00:00 (WED)


2024-09-23 04:48:00 (MON)
5
2024-09-30 04:48:00 (MON)



fiddle
